# How to pass Non English character to request in AFNetworking iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

How to encode/set UTF-8 Non English characters (e.g, Chinese character 我) to request in AFNetworking iOS?

My code:

```
    NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:self.httpManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
    [contentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
    [contentTypes addObject:@"text/html"];
    [contentTypes addObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
    [contentTypes addObject:@"charset=UTF-8"];
    [contentTypes addObject:@"application/json"];

    self.httpManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =
    [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"text/plain",
                          @"text/html",
                          @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                          @"charset=UTF-8",
                          @"application/json"]];
```

The backend will get something like this

> å��æ��å¸�

instead of the correct characters.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that your backend is decoding with something else than UTF 8?

Comment: @Pochi I am not sure since I cannot touch the backend code, but it works for Android app..

Comment: @Rendy did you get same data when you try to call service in Postman?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh the API works fine in the app just the encode is not correct yet

Comment: Check answer, if it's helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is the solution:

```
[self.httpManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue one of my application. Below is my code, hope it will help you.

```
NSData *data = [strStringWithUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
if(goodValue == nil)
    return strStringWithUnicode;
return goodValue;
```